# Mysql 1064 error cant spot the obvious mistake

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
SELECT `Order`.`Account` AS Account ,`Order`.`OrderNumber` AS OrderNo   
,`TWOrder`.`Customer` , `TWOrder`.`WorksOrderNumber`, `TWOrder`.`Product`,    
`Stock`.`ProductNumber`, `Stock`.`Description` AS description   
,`Bundle`.`WorksOrder`,`Bundle`.`WorkSection` FROM Order, TWOrder, Stock, Bundle, WHERE 
`Order`.`Account` = `TWOrder`.`Customer` AND`TWOrder`.`WorksOrderNumber` = 
`Bundle`.`WorksOrder` AND `TWOrder`.`Product` = `Stock`.`Description` AND   
 `Order`.`Account` = '337447'
```

I've check and spotted the obvious but I cant seem the error. Would appreciate another pair of eyes

Comment: try FROM \`Order\` (since order is a keyword) and no comma before WHERE

Answer (score 2):

You had a comma in the wrong place - i think this should work (and it is a bit more readable)

```
    SELECT `Order`.`Account` AS Account,
           `Order`.`OrderNumber` AS OrderNo,
           `TWOrder`.`Customer`,
           `TWOrder`.`WorksOrderNumber`,
           `TWOrder`.`Product`,    
           `Stock`.`ProductNumber`,
           `Stock`.`Description` AS description,
           `Bundle`.`WorksOrder`,
           `Bundle`.`WorkSection`
   FROM `Order`, TWOrder, Stock, Bundle
   WHERE 
    `Order`.`Account` = `TWOrder`.`Customer` AND 
    `TWOrder`.`WorksOrderNumber` = `Bundle`.`WorksOrder` AND
    `TWOrder`.`Product` = `Stock`.`Description` AND
    `Order`.`Account` = '337447'
```